# Factory Girl: Use same object several times

Tags: ruby, json, factory-bot

I'm building a factory method that will to save some information in JSON for later analysis in an app that cuts boards.

These boards will have plating around them, so the JSON will contain the ids for each one of its boarders.

For example, we can have Platings 1 and 2.

And I need to generate boards that may look like this:

```
width: 500
height: 500
platings: {"up": 1, left: 2, right: 1}
```

So I can have more than once an id on a single Factory, but I have no way to do it since every time I create a plating I will get another ID.

This is an example of what I have tried to do

```
Factory :medium_board do
  width 500
  height 500
  platings {{
    "up": create(:plating).id, #id: 1 OK
    "left": create(:another_plating).uuid, #id: 2, OK
    "right": create(:plating).uuid #id: 3, NOT OK, should have been 1.
  }}
end
```

Is there something fundamental that I am skipping?
Which is the best way to do this?
Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an `after` hook here. Something like this:

```
factory :medium_board do

  after :build do |board|
    plating1 = create(:plating)
    plating2 = create(:another_plating)

    board.platings = {
      up: plating1.id,
      left: plating2.id,
      right: plating1.id,
    }
  end
end
```